# Terminate workflow with Sharepoint 2013 Rest API

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-addin

I was required to cancel some of running workflows. Is there any way to cancel or terminate Workflow using Sharepoint 2013 Rest API?

Answer (score 0):

There is not unless you build your own custom server side code with a REST endpoint exposure. The only front-end way to do it out of the box is through the workflow page for the list item and clicking 'End Workflow'.